# Probability Models (Poisson Process)

Tags: probability-theory

There are two types of claims that are made to an insurance company. Let $\ N_{i}(t)$ denote the number of type i claims made by time t, and suppose that $\{N_{1}(t): t \ge 0\}$  and  $\{N_{2}(t): t \ge 0\}$ are independent Poisson  processes with rate $\lambda_{1}=10 $ and $\lambda_{2}=1 $. The amounts of successive type 1 claims are indenpendent exponential random variables with mean 1000 dollars whereas the amounts from type 2 claims are independent exponential random variables with mean 5000 dollars. A claim for 4000 dollars has just been received; what is the probability it is a type 1 claim?

(Attempt)
Let $T_{1}$ : Time that type 1 first arrives

Let $T_{2}$ : Time that type 2 first arrives

Then, $P(1)=P(T_{1}<T_{2})$=  $\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}}$ =$\frac{10}{11}$

$P(2)=P(T_{2}<T_{1})$=$\frac{1}{11}$

By Bayes rule,
$P(1|4000)$=$\frac{P(4000|1)P(1)}{P(4000|1)P(1)+P(4000|2)p(2)}$

I don't know how to get $P(4000|1)$ and $P(4000|2)$.

I need some help.